# Django Rest Framework OPTIONS request - include initial/default choices

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using options to populate `select` inputs in my project. Is there a way to include also information about `default` values?

For this field:

```
DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_ONLY = 'shipping_only'
DELIVERY_METHOD__LOCAL_PICKUP_ONLY = 'local_pickup_only'
DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_AND_LOCAL_PICKUP = 'shipping_and_local_pickup'
DELIVERY_METHOD_CHOICES = (
    (DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_ONLY, 'Shipping only'),
    (DELIVERY_METHOD__LOCAL_PICKUP_ONLY, 'Local pickup only'),
    (DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_AND_LOCAL_PICKUP, 'Shipping & local pickup'),
)
delivery_method = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=DELIVERY_METHOD_CHOICES,
                                   default=DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_ONLY)
```

The OPTIONS `actions.POST.delivery_method` is this:

```
        "delivery_method": {
            "type": "choice",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": false,
            "label": "Delivery method",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "value": "shipping_only",
                    "display_name": "Shipping only"
                },
                {
                    "value": "local_pickup_only",
                    "display_name": "Local pickup only"
                },
                {
                    "value": "shipping_and_local_pickup",
                    "display_name": "Shipping & local pickup"
                }
            ]
        },
```

But it should also say that `Shipping only` is the default one so I can prepopulate the input with this value.

Is there a built-in way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to throw 'initial' in there like so;

```py
delivery_method = models.CharField(
   max_length=32,
   choices=DELIVERY_METHOD_CHOICES,
   default=DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_ONLY,
   initial=DELIVERY_METHOD__SHIPPING_ONLY,
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such option in models. Maybe I could do that in the serializer.

Comment: What are you using to generate the OPTIONS request?

Comment: It's the default one. I use ModelViewSets.